# Subsetting a dataframe in R by max value and additional condition on the same variable

Tags: r

I am new in R. Hopefully this is not a question that was asked before...

I am trying to subset a dataframe based on the criteria:

a. Highest value for certain ID

b. The value is at least twice as high as the next value on the list for the same ID.

The df looks like this (edited):

```
  > example_df_25
       df.qry.names        df.hit.len
1      10008                  407
2      10008                  181
3      10008                  166
4      10008                  160
5      10008                  146
6      10008                  145
7      10008                  120
8      10008                  101
9      10008                   96
10     10008                   93
11     10008                   85
12     10008                   83
13     10008                   83
14     10008                   58
15     10008                   56
16     10015                  462
17     10015                  350
18     10015                  193
19     10015                  160
20     10015                  154
21     10015                  152
22     10015                  138
23     10015                   66
24     10039                  501
25     10039                  406
```

And the subset that i would like to get is:

```
 df.qry.names   hit.len 
  1 10008     407
```

here is a dput(df) output:

```
structure(list(df.qry.names = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("10008", "10015", 
"10039"),class = "factor"), df.hit.len = c(407L, 
181L, 166L, 160L, 146L, 145L, 120L, 101L, 96L, 93L, 85L, 83L, 
83L, 58L, 56L, 462L, 350L, 193L, 160L, 154L, 152L, 138L, 66L, 
501L, 406L)), .Names = c("df.qry.names", "df.hit.len"
), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

I understand how to subset a df, based on a maximal value with data.table, but how do I get it with the 2-nd condition, that it is not just the max value, but twice as high as related to the next one for the same ID? Does it necessarily go with a loop?
Hope there is a quicker solution...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

with dplyr you can do the following:
group by id and order by hit.len, divide hit.len by the lead of hit.len and filter the ones bigger or equal to 2.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, desc(hit.len)) %>% 
  mutate(high = hit.len / lead(hit.len, n = 1L)) %>% 
  filter(high >= 2 ) %>% 
  select(id, hit.len)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id hit.len
  <int>  <int>
1 10008    407
2 10029   1000
```

data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(10008L, 10008L, 10008L, 10008L, 10008L, 10008L, 10020L, 10020L, 10020L, 10029L, 10029L, 10029L), 
               hitlen = c(407L, 181L, 166L, 146L, 145L, 160L, 80L, 86L, 96L, 1000L, 87L, 111L)), 
          .Names = c("id", "hit.len"), 
          class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")

dt <- fread(
"id     hit.len 
10008     407    
10008     181    
10008     166    
10008     146    
10008     145    
10008     160
10020     80
10020     86
10020     96
10029    1000
10029    111
10029    87")
dt[, cond:= (hit.len==max(hit.len)) & (hit.len >= 2*shift(hit.len, type="lead")), by=id][(cond)]
#       id hit.len cond
# 1: 10008     407 TRUE
# 2: 10029    1000 TRUE
```

If you want the maximum value at least twice as high as the second greatest value, then you can first sort the data.table:

```
setorder(dt, id, -hit.len)
```

Here is a small example of how effects `type="lead"`:

```
shift(1:5) # or shift(1:5, type="lag")
shift(1:5, type="lead")
```

If you have a dataframe `df` you can coerce it into a data.table-object in place by:

```
setDT(df)
```

#### For your example dataframe (dput):

```
df <- structure(list(df.qry.names = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("10008", "10015", 
       "10039"),class = "factor"), df.hit.len = c(407L,  
       181L, 166L, 160L, 146L, 145L, 120L, 101L, 96L, 93L, 85L, 83L, 
     83L, 58L, 56L, 462L, 350L, 193L, 160L, 154L, 152L, 138L, 66L, 
          501L, 406L)), .Names = c("df.qry.names", "df.hit.len"
              ), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame") 
###
library("data.table")
setDT(df)
df[, cond:= (df.hit.len==max(df.hit.len)) & (df.hit.len >= 2*shift(df.hit.len, type="lead")), by=df.qry.names][(cond)]
```

Comment: Thanks very much! You've been a great help @jogo and @phiver!

Comment: Update: Although data.table was more intuitive for me, couldn't do "shift" with hit.len variable. Got an error: "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shift’ for signature ‘"integer"’.  Worked like charm with dplyr. Thanks again, @phiver!

Comment: I put here a tiny subset of a huge DF. a dput will be enormous. Would you like to put a type of a variable or anything else that may be of help instead? Thank you!

Comment: data.table_1.10.4-3

Comment: I edited my answer. I can not reproduce the issue. (works without any error)